# Floating action button not displaying over recyclerview(which is inside a DrawerLayout)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I am trying to get FAB over recyclerview which in my case will cover the whole screen. The FAB wont display even recyclerview is empty. Following is my xml code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.technistan.ledger.CreateLedger"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            ></include>


        <FrameLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                />


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/myFAB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:elevation="4dp" />


        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.technistan.ledger.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The preview is showing floating button fine like in the below snap;
https://www.dropbox.com/s/18u5pt5v6kkkibj/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-13%20at%201.19.20%20PM.png?dl=0

But when i run the app there is no FAB displayed. I had tried many combinations but couldn't succeed.
I tried this over listview without navigationdrawer (simple activity and it was working there i.e. displayed over listview).

Any help will be appreciated guys. Thanks

**[EDIT:]** I think the problem is because of the parent layout i.e. android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, I had copy pasted the code from start of  to its end  to another empty activity and it shows the floating button over it there. But still unable to figure it out how to resolve this issue, I nee to display floating action button inside the Drawerlayout.

Comment: have you tried to change the sizes to fixed values?

Comment: which sizes to be precise?

Comment: of your containers (LinearLayout, FrameLayout) just to be sure the FloatingActionButton is realy not visible

Comment: Yes! But thats the issue because its displaying in activity without DrawerLayout as i mention above in the [Edit]

Comment: I have the same problem , but I use frame layout  as parent one , not DrawerLayout. any idea?

Comment: @Nininea Need to see your layout code to find the exact problem. But try using CoordinatorLayout instead of Frame..

Comment: I fixed it, it was due linear layout what I used too

Answer (score 17):

Try it like this :

Remove all layouts.

Keep only one parent, that's `CoordinatorLayout`.

Inside `CoordinatorLayout`, put both your `RecyclerView` and `FloatingActionButton`.

`CoordinatorLayout` should auto arrange your toolbar, recycler and fab, since is programmed to handle the design support library components.

Here's an example. You can use `RecyclerView` in place of the FrameLayout (which dynamically loads fragments at runtime). I generally use `RecyclerView` in another `Fragment` and load the fragment in here at runtime. This keeps the xml files clean.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <!-- Main layout for fragment placing -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/pink"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/pink_pressed"
        app:borderWidth = "0dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- Nav drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/pink_pressed"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Also you can follow this nice tutorial to get a hang of the stuff. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: Why this answer unselected. Anyways helped me thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try using FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout as your root layout. That worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the LinearLayout, that seems not be the problem.

I'm pretty sure your solution will be fixed by moving the RecyclerView under the FAB button.

In other words, in the XML layout, move the FAB button block of code, over the RecyclerView block of code.

An example:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:elevation="4dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Order matters due to the way android system draws it's views.

You might see other artifacts but the FAB button should at least be visible now.

Comment: I done what you say but still cant see the FAB. Here is the link to my screen shot of code and preview. In preview its showing fine.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nwHKjoiUubTnF0cnhsUFBRSUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is how it shows on emulator https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nwHKjoiUubOWRuMnRHVU5PbE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @tariq in your screenshot it seems you have declared your floating action button before your recycler view. Try swapping the order so recycler view first is first. Also what level is your emulator? Because elevation is only reflected in lollipop and up. If still no good can you screenshot with "show layout bounds" turned on in developer options?

Comment: View appearing last in the XML is always drawn on top on older Android versions. This solution is incorrect.

Comment: @Gary I tried the floating action button below and above the recyclerview but it did not shows. finally I created a new activity and pasted the code there and it worked. thanks for the help anyways :)

Answer (score -2):

I had just created a new activity and copy pasted the whole code there and its working fine there. I still dont know the issue that what was wrong. But it worked for me this way. I had compared line by line code in two activities and they are same. Its just that floating action button is displaying in new activity and not in the old.

any ways thanks for all the help from community who tried.

Comment: Maybe the issue was in the Activity's code and not the layout's code.

Comment: but it did the same for activity as well copy pasted the logic code to new class file. I am still searching what I did wrong there.

Answer (score -2):

It should be because of androidmanifest.xml. 
When you add a new activity it is automatically added in androidmanifest.xml with right permission.