# Floating action button unintentionally floats to top of screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

The FAB seems to overlap the toolbar at the top of the screen, whereas I want it at the bottom right of the screen.

If I modify the layout_height of the app_bar_main.xml element (contains toolbar and button) to "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content", the button gets correctly placed but then the fragment which should be there gets pushed off the screen/is not placed.

Issue seems to be with the structure of the xml files but I am not sure how to fix it.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_action_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="#FFF"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFF"
        app:menu="@menu/loggedout_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_login.xml** (Layout of fragment that is placed in main_container)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_action_bar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Login."
            android:id="@+id/login_title_text"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAlt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <!-- E-mail section -->
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="E-mail address"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/login_emailField"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_title_text" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/register_email_icon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/login_emailField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


        <!-- Password section -->
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_emailField"
            android:id="@+id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/register_password_icon"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/login_login_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_passwordField"
            android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#E91E63"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/material_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="Login" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Forgotten your username or password?"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_login_button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/login_footer_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Tap here"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@id/login_footer_text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/loginForgottenTapText"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You need to have `main_container`  inside the CoordinatorLayout in order for it to display correctly, see the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546627/floating-action-button-not-displaying-over-recyclerviewwhich-is-inside-a-drawer

Comment: Seems to have fixed it, only issue now is the FAB will go as far down the screen as the elements on there, does not seem to be aligned bottom parent.

Comment: Make sure that you have values for `@dimen/fab_margin`